# How many parallel processes?

Tags: perl, concurrency, parallel-processing, fork

I am running some code in parallel by using a forking module in `perl` called `Parallel::ForkManager`. I have currently setting the maximum number of processes to `30`:

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(30);
```

What would be an advisable maximum number of processes to create?  I am doing this on a commercial grade Solaris server, but I still don't want to overload the system.

Comment: As a general rule, it is reasonable to set the max number of processes to some small multiple of the total number of processors available (2x is a common choice).  But it really depends on your application, and you definitely need to test different settings to see what works best for you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Well, the server in question has 1 physical processor and 30 virtual processors. I seem to be able to fork 30 processes with no trouble.

Comment: Make the statment "I seem to be able to..." more precise.  Identify key metrics that matter to you, then change the parameter and see how those metrics are impacted.

Comment: It just works with no obvious problems.  I haven't measured anything.  I wouldn't really know how to.  This is a server in a work environment which I don't have administrator/root privileges on.  The sample code for the perl module does 30 processes.

Comment: I like to set it to a number lesser than the number of available processors. That way I have a every chance that each thing runs in its own core, and I don't take the whole machine.  If your code is actually concurrent (and not purely parallel) then it may make more sense running multiple processes on one core.  Time the speedup with dfferent choices, that shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: The limit to how many you _can_ fork is probably very high, so it will work without problems if you run 30 or 60.  The question is what is optimal, ie. how much you are gaining (if any!) as you keep increasing that.  First time your program with different choices, you don't need any privilages for that.  As you keep increasing the number you'll see that the speedup drops at some point, and then it drops sharply.

Comment: @zdim I am using it download a large number of files in parallel. So if I fork 30 processes then the speed increase is 30 times.

Comment: Oh, with that it's a little different, that will be I/O bound.  Try to go further and time it.  The first concern is that you don't jam the system or annoy other people.  I would think that it is going to be more important how much you're pushing the I/O . I wouldn't go beyond the "reasonable" as [William Pursell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) told you, but that's just me.  You do have a server you say but I'd look into I/O loads and behavior.  Speficy your situation further (edit) and hopefully some more knowledgable people will pitch in.

Comment: Downloading files is I/O bound, not CPU bound, so you may not get much improvement by forking. Your biggest bottlenecks will be the network and file I/O, not CPU usage.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot If it takes 5 seconds to download each file then by forking 30 processes it will mean the first 30 downloads will take 5 seconds instead of 150 seconds.

Comment: @CJ7 "Anything running in parallel will be quicker." Wrong. You can only download a fixed amount of data per second through a network interface, and you can only write a fixed amount of data to disk per second. It doesn't matter how many processes you fork or how many cores you use, you can only shove so much data through a network interface at a time. In fact, in some cases, forking actually decreases performance because it creates extra overhead.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot see my edited comment. Each download has to wait to finish.  By running them in parallel you are not waiting.  30 downloads can occur simultaneously.  My script is taking about 5 mins to run when it used to take over an hour.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot There is a bottleneck when an HTTP connection is made.  This has nothing to do with bandwidth.  These connections can occur in parallel.

Comment: @CJ7 30 downloads can occur simultaneously, but if you're constrained by network and/or disk I/O, each one will take longer to finish than if they were run serially. Forking does not magically increase your network bandwidth or disk speed. The only way to know if it improves performance for your particular system is to benchmark it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot While I understand the point you are making, my own evidence is that a script is taking minutes instead of hours to run. That's what I am trying to explain.  I think it is because the HTTP connection operation is time consuming which is something quite apart from the downloading operation which I agree is just a function of bandwidth.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you did do a rough benchmark. Think about it this way: you multiplied your number of processes by 30, but you only multiplied your throughput by about 18 (if downloading 150 files total, you have 150 files/5 minutes = 30 files/minute compared to 150 files/>1 hour, say 150 files/90 minutes = 1.67 files/minute). That's a good boost, but if you had a CPU-bound process, your performance multiplier would be a lot closer to 30. Anyway, you should test with different numbers of processes until you find the sweet spot for your application and system.

Comment: You are almost certainly going to depend on I/O capabilities of your server, and on typical loads (from other jobs) at the time at which you do this.  At some machines you'll see saturation at 4-5 simultaneous I/O bound processes, some can take far more. You can probably push the number of processes but at some point your I/O will start coughing.  Time it, step by step.  Also watch some measure of I/O loads. I wouldn't push it past 2-per-core anyway -- at some point you will just have too many processes, regardless of performance.

Comment: If you share the machine with others I'd advise you to be careful.  Jamming I/O isn't funny.  People can't work anymore. I'd do the following: Time in steps, from say 5 processes upward.  When you notice that the speed up drops, back up a bit.  If it drops at 15, work at 10 or 12.  Better go for 10 sec rather than 5 -- but not hurt others.  If this runs for a long time (or often) you'd want to back up far more. This affects many other things.

Comment: Just realized a critical piece: Are you downloading files from a web server? If you hit a server with 50 requests a second they'll shut you down (blacklist the IP) very quickly, and that's that.  When you go to a server you _wait_, not fork.  More than say 2/s is not "polite" (an important word in that business), for all I know.  I normally `sleep` for a second, or more if my timing sees that the server is busy. If you go to a 'normal' web server then that's your bottleneck.

Comment: @zadim Yes I am downloading files from a web server.  I am experiencing some failed downloads with the response described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714411/cant-download-file-using-user-agent

Comment: I'm not sure why you've placed a bounty. The *only* possible  useful answer to this question is that you must experiment to find what works best for *this particular* workload, and you've already been told that. You also seem to be supremely confident in your assertions about the behavior of the system ("If it takes 5 seconds to download... "), which, again, makes it hard to understand what you're looking for that you don't already know or can't find out through experimentation. You also received quite a bit of interesting information in the comments, so...what more do you want?

Comment: @KyleStrand I want to know how many processes should generally be run in parallel.  This might depend on factors such as number of CPUs (or cores), RAM etc.

Comment: @KyleStrand I want to know how many processes I can run without the server grinding to a halt or crashing.

Comment: @CJ7 Having taken a class on analyzing the effect of multiprocessing on different workloads, the main takeaway was "it depends." Seriously. This is something you *must* simply benchmark for yourself. As for crashing the server, you should see massive slowdown with fewer processes than the number required to *crash* the server, so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: To put a fine point on what KyleStrand is saying, your question is one that cannot be answered the way you stated it. zdim outlines the procedure for benchmarking your program, but there's a step you need to take before you even do that: you need to define what you mean by "overload the system". Do you mean crash the system? Make it temporarily unresponsive? Saturate the network? After that, the benchmarking is up to you since it depends directly on the behavior of your program and your hardware.

Answer (score 5):

In downloading files, this really depends on

1. how many different hosts you're downloading from, and
2. how fast they will give you the requested files compared to your maximum bandwidth.

If you're downloading files from a single machine to a single machine on a local network, 2-3 is about max.  If you're downloading files from 30 different servers on the internet, all of which are slow, but you have a fat pipe, then 30 might be reasonable.

There is no one universal right answer here.  Unless you count "it depends."

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of "*downloading files*" was mentioned, but in comments a while ago and I take the question as stated, to also be more general.

---

The only relevant measure is when you start reaching saturation in performance gains, with particular software on that system. The formal limits are huge and meaningless while rules of thumb are very general.

Let's imagine to run 10 processes and the time to complete the job drops 10 times. Increase to 20 processes and the time drops 20 times -- but for 30 processes the gain is the factor of 10. At this point we *have* loaded the system.  Push further and the performance will degrade rapidly, and for everyone.  At that point the server *is* overloaded, even though it allows, say, 1024 processes per user (and really ten or more times that for a server).

With a few processes per core the machine is engaged and I'd say that that is a good rule of thumb. However, it is too general. I doubt that you'd gain much in performance by going to that many processes, given the many other factors that affect it.

**Accessing one web server**   The server's capability is the gospel. They may have posted how many requests per seconds they are happy with. Or they may have a limit on number of processes per user, say 10 or 20. If that means that many simultaneous downloads then that's your limit. But I'd be careful -- if the site is close and fast a request may complete in as little as 0.1 or 0.2 seconds. Then, with 10 processes you may be hitting the server 100 times a second. I do not recommend that. If there is no information I'd say keep it to a few requests per second. The performance and server load also depend on the content -- big downloads are different from pulling many skinny web pages. The I/O on your side may matter but I'd expect the server to set the limit.  If you are going to use their service a lot why not send an email and ask what they are OK with.

**I/O, network (many servers) or disk**    With network the performance depends on every piece of hardware in the path as well as on software.  Nobody can tell without trying it out.  The disk I/O is very complex.  To add to trouble it is unclear whether it'd be your disks or network that is the bottleneck.  I'd expect clear performance gains up to a few tens of processes, and probably fewer.

**CPU or memory bound**    This may be easiest -- processing that can be broken up in parallel on 30 cores can enjoy close to a factor of 30 speedup (given no other bottlenecks).  Going beyond the number of cores clearly leads to reduced performance gain. Concurrent (but not parallel) processing is far more complicated. If your code is memory intensive that is yet completely different.

Useful basic tools for assessing above components are `iostat -xzn`, `netstat -I`, and `vmstat`.  But there is a bit of a curve to learning how to interpret their output and hopefully it doesn't come to that.

---

The conclusion is that you have to time it. Take your real application and time it running in one process. Do this 3 to 5 times and see the average (throw away obvious outliers). Then repeat with 5 processes, then with 10, etc.  I'd expect that the trend will start slowing down far sooner than the 30 processors you mention.  Once it gets to that the system is loaded and whoever works on it will notice. Very soon after that the performance will likely degrade rapidly. Proper benchmarking tools, like [`Benchmark`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html), are far more sophisticated but this may well settle the issue.  If you see strange or inconsistent behavior you may have to dig into details, starting with tools mentioned above.

What "*overloaded*" means is a bit unclear.  I like to cap my use of resources well before other people are affected.  But it may be possible to push it, in particular if you can run when it's quiet.  I doubt that you'll keep having a worthy gain all the way to the number of available processors.

So there is no concern about "*overloading*" the server if you first time things.  The performance limit will tell you when to stop. I'd say that your limit of 30 is very reasonable. Unless this is really about downloading files, in which case the web server is likely all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the maximum number of processes to 60.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @John Because grizzly bears.